# FileVault decryption accidentially started - what will happen?

Tags: mac, filevault

I accidentially started to decrypt my FileVault so I am wondering what is the process?

Will it reset my computer so I will have to put in my info?
Or will It just start up again and ask for my password?

Comment: Welcome to Ask Different. There are several versions of macOS that implement FileVault in slightly different manners. MIght you be able to edit the question to show what you see for the version number or the view that shows it decrypting?

Answer (score 1):

FileVault decryption does not erase any data or reset your computer.

When the decryption process is finished, the computer will be just like before - except that the data on disk is no longer encrypted. You can use the computer while it is decryption.

As this was done by accident, it is a good idea to enable FileVault again when it is done decrypting. It will unfortunately take a while to encrypt again, but you can use the machine while it is encryption.

There's no way of stopping the current decryption process to immediately encrypt again. You'll have to wait for it to be fully decrypted, and then enable FileVault again.

Comment: but will I have to use a recovery key

Comment: there are alot of important stuff on there so I am a little worried

Comment: No, you don’t have to use a recovery key. Don’t worry - nothing at all happens to your data. You can keep using the computer just as you did before. The only difference is that data isn’t encrypted on the drive. I would recommend enabling FileVault again when it’s done.

Comment: I have 1 last question then how come at the filevault tab it tells you warning: you need a recovery key or else all data will be lost

Comment: Where does it say that?

Comment: on top of the turn off filevault buttom

Comment: have you ever decrypted filevault before?

Comment: Yes. Please include a screenshot or the exact wording. You do not need a recovery key after decrypting.

Comment: oh I'm sorry I read it wrong it said you will need a login password OR a recovery key sorry for bothering you and thank you for answering my dumb question